# Mongo: update all fields, but merge some

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in my collections:

```json
{
  "key": "abc",
  "field1": "oldValue",
  "fieldN": ["a","b"]
}
```

Now I have documents like this:

```json
{
  "key": "abc",
  "field1": "newValue",
  "fieldN": ["b","c"]
}
```

Is it possible (in a single operation) to update a document (if `key` matches) with new values (overwrite), but for a single `fieldN` field perform a merge operation: `["a", "b"] + ["b", "c"]` becomes `["a", "b", "c"]` (unique values, order does not matter)

And if document `key` does not exist perform a simple insert (I think I can do this with `upsert` flag)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$addToSet` :

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { key: "abc" },
    { $set: { field1: "newValue" }, $addToSet: { fieldN: { $each: ["b", "c"] } } },
    { upsert: true }
);
```

Comment: What if I have many fields to replace, but only one field to merge. Can I somehow simplify request to use original JSON document (+`$addToSet` for single field) without manually converting it to multiple `$set` commands?

Comment: you can use the `$set` operator in combination with `$addToSet` to update multiple fields and merge one field